# Can we resize a already capped collection in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I have a capped collection whose initial size i gave 3 GB.
Can I modify its size again i mean reducing or increasing both way as per need?
is there any command to do it.

```
db.HourwiseArticleCount.stats(1024*1024);
{
    "ns" : "DB.HourwiseArticleCount",
    "count" : 7055875,
    "size" : 2554,
    "avgObjSize" : 379,
    "storageSize" : 2662,
    "numExtents" : 2,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "lastExtentSize" : 615,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 669,
    "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 218
    },
    "capped" : true,
    "max" : NumberLong("9223372036854775807"),
    "ok" : 1
}
db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "HourwiseArticleCount", size: 2362232012});
db.HourwiseArticleCount.stats(1024*1024);
{
    "ns" : "DB.HourwiseArticleCount",
    "count" : 5968662,
    "size" : 2161,
    "avgObjSize" : 379,
    "storageSize" : 2252,
    "numExtents" : 2,
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "lastExtentSize" : 205,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 184,
    "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 184
    },
    "capped" : true,
    "max" : NumberLong("9223372036854775807"),
    "ok" : 1
}
db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "HourwiseArticleCount", size:2147483648});
db.HourwiseArticleCount.stats(1024*1024);
{
    "ns" : "DB.HourwiseArticleCount",
    "count" : 5422132,
    "size" : 1965,
    "avgObjSize" : 380,
    "storageSize" : 2048,
    "numExtents" : 3,
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "lastExtentSize" : 0,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 167,
    "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 167
    },
    "capped" : true,
    "max" : NumberLong("9223372036854775807"),
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: @AdamC the solution in that post is for increasing the size is is possible to decrease the size without down time

Comment: If you read the answer it says: "you can't alter a capped collection size without dropping it and recreating it" - so no, resizing of any type is not possible, up or down, it is fixed.

Comment: @AdamC sorry to interrupt again but i saw one post for this and i was not confirmed with that can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225535/how-can-i-resize-a-mongodb-capped-collection-without-losing-data

Comment: Again, if you read the answer, that is not resizing a capped collection, that is creating a new capped collection and copying the documents over from the old one - you would have to stop all writes to do it, and using javascript it would not be particularly fast.  Until SERVER-1864 is implemented resizing capped collections is not possible

Comment: @AdamC Thanks for the input Ya without down time resizing is not possible as i checked on staging I followed these steps:   1. Stop write n Read in that collection.                       2.db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "coll", size: 2791728742}); on same collection.                            3. Re indexing and open it for read n write                  I did not need to take dump and restore it.

Comment: It's not possible at all - what you have done is used the command to convert a non-capped collection to capped.  That does not resize an existing capped collection, because resizing a capped collection is simply *not* possible at present (with or without down time).  You can only create new, drop old and copy data between (with mongodump, javascript etc.)

Comment: @AdamC i might be doing something wrong but i just posted teh collection stats if you see the collection was capped and i run command again to resize it then it was in new size with capped true again. I did it two times.If you take a look it is what id did. Yup i need to recreate indexes though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21216/discussion-between-viren-and-adam-c).

Comment: convertToCapped clones the data to a new collection, drops the old one, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11256419/1148648

Comment: Which  simply means that we do not need to take dump and restore it at same collection can be resize using same mechanism